# Android long running services with webSockets

Tags: android, websocket, service, firebase-cloud-messaging, background-process

Trying to make an custom app services package (like facebook services) installed with the app APK

Hi folks , since a year i start trying to make an custom app services package (like facebook services) , the desired result that i wish to accomplich which i need my app background web socket (that fetch a highly rated notifications) that run inside a service  , but almost the Androd OS hate this type of apps , any advice about this topic , Note i tried the leak canary mechanism which it install a sparated launcher activity but its not work , the FCM in last few years not doing well even with paid plans , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your question you are trying to stay at the background as much as you can. Even if app was closed or background/foreground. Let me share some magic with you)

First, let's declare some broadcast receiver in order to ask android for pinging your application after reboot (I guess you need it anyway).
Manifest declaration

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<receiver
    android:name=".MyReceiver"
    android:exported="false"
    android:enabled="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then create class for your receiver.

```
class MyReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) { }
    
        companion object{
            fun enable(){
                getAppContext().packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    ComponentName(getAppContext(), MyReceiver::class.java),
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                )
            }
    
            fun disable(){
                getAppContext().packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                    ComponentName(getAppContext(), MyReceiver::class.java), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

By doing this way you asking android to awake your app after device reboot and keep it alive as much as possible with DONT_KILL_APP. Awaking you app means that code in your application class will be triggered as well, and this is the place where you can do your logic - check if you socket still opened, open if needed or launch your service or simply do whatever you need! It will enlarge amount of your background.

Another trick - you can use work manager in order to schedule some useless lightweight work in backgroud like infinite loop that will sleep for some time between iterations. Be careful with threading don't block ui! Schedule work manager to execute this work periodically with the minimum 15 mins and permissions like internet. By doing this way you will ask android to provide net/processor recourses for your application. Also there is the way to be awaked during maintenance window when you device in doze mode.

Follow this guidelines and you will receive a lot of background time. But you should be careful and use your resources responsible in order to stay alive as much as android allow you. Hope it will be handy for you.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, I'll try this technique.